# request returning "Endpoint request timed out"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, timeout

I have deployed a flask app on aws lambda using zappa now the app is running fine on all end points except my main one when i give post request on it it returns 
{
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}

really need a fix or idea how to over come this i need to call the analysis route, the deployed url is

https://2ixfyfcsik.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev

tried increasing my app timeout limit none avail it seems api gateway has 30 second time out so how to by pass that or not how to make my app return results in 30 seconds any help appreciated

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import os,json
from hatesonar import Sonar
from profanityfilter import ProfanityFilter


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)



@app.route('/',methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify({"message": "Hello World!"})



@app.route('/test',methods = ['GET'])
def test():
    results=[]
    post="Every Day. Narrated by Patch."
    sonar = Sonar()
    offensiveLanguage = sonar.ping(text=post)
    for item in offensiveLanguage['classes']:
        if (item['class_name']=='hate_speech'):
            if(item['confidence']>=0.9):
                hatesonar_hatespeech=item['coinfidence']
            else:
                hatesonar_hatespeech=0
            results.append(hatesonar_hatespeech)
        else:
            pass
        if (item['class_name']=='offensive_language'):
            if(item['confidence']>=0.9):
                hatesonar_swearing=item['coinfidence']
            else:
                hatesonar_swearing=0
            results.append(hatesonar_swearing)
    return jsonify(results)




@app.route('/offensiveLanguage',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      user = request.form['nm']
      return redirect(url_for('success',name = user))
   else:
      sonar = Sonar()
      text = request.args.get('text')
      print("text", text)
      offensiveLanguage = sonar.ping(text=text)
      print("offensiveLanguage", offensiveLanguage)
      return jsonify(offensiveLanguage)


@app.route('/analysis',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def profanity():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profanitycount=0
        data = request.get_json()
        posts=[]
        for item in data:
            if ('media' in item):
                for x in item['media']:
                    if(x['mediaType']=='post'):
                        if (x['content']):
                            posts.append(x['content'])
                        else:
                            pass
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
        flat_list = []
        for sublist in posts:
            for item in sublist:
                flat_list.append(item)          
        for post in flat_list:
            pf = ProfanityFilter()
            swearing = pf.is_profane(post)
            if(swearing=='true'):
                profanitycount = profanitycount + 1
            else:
                profanitycount = profanitycount
            sonar = Sonar()
            offensiveLanguage = sonar.ping(text=post)   
    print("profanity", profanitycount)
    return jsonify(profanitycount)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that your profanity() is actually being invoked, but it's simply taking too long to yield a result?

Comment: yes as all the results are coming locally, all other routes work as well when i have deployed its just analysis that yields request timeout but works fine locally...

Comment: Is your Lambda in a VPC?

Comment: Your profanity() method looks fairly simple. Why don't you add some print statements to it and then check CloudWatch Logs afterwards to see what the code is doing? Temporarily bypass the hatesonar code to see if it's the cause.

Comment: do you mean that it has nothing to do with for loops and everything in the function what can ideally cause a timeout. i believed that perhaps the functions takes too long to return results thats why its returning request time out.

Comment: We don't know. That's why you have to add some diagnostics to your code so that you know which line of code seems to be causing the timeout. Usually, it will be because of a network timeout trying to access a remote resource, which is either not responding (their problem) or which is not reachable (your problem). Please also answer the earlier question: is this Lambda in a VPC? That changes things significantly.

Comment: @ZainAamir by the way, please tag people when you are responding to them in comments otherwise they won't get notified and may not see your post to them. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work for more.

Comment: @jarmod sir i am sorry i do not know if it is on a vpc or not i am newbie i just use zappa deploy and zappa dev to push my app the current status is as such

Comment: @jarmod ok i did a little bit of printing and found out.now i will explain i have posts and images that i scrape of a website then i apply nlp and cloud vision api then run it seemed that the data was too much cause first it loops through posts then it loops through images locally fine but on aws cloud watch it would loop posts then loop images then in btw time out now i solved it by reduced my data in the post request to a minimum but now how to fix this that all data can be taken up and used and then output can be returned.

Answer (score 1):

if your request is sync then try to increase memory in Basic Setting of lambda. It was worked for me (Your function is allocated CPU proportional to the memory configured).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-threading to decrease the response time.

This link may be helpful for you [AWS Lambda And Multi Threading Using Python](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/aws-lambda-and-multi-threading-using-python-62352d632e)

Answer (score 0):

Mid-2022 there is now an official solution that bypasses the API Gateway and hence the annoying 29 second limit:
[AWS Lambda Function URLs: Built-in HTTPS Endpoints for Single-Function Microservices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/)

> ... sometimes all you need is a simple way to configure an HTTPS endpoint in front of your function without having to learn, configure, and operate additional services besides Lambda.

The Lambda basically spins off it's own express server and communicates directly with the internet, without imposing API Gateway limits on the communication